# jQuery UI tabs: How do I load a specific element from a different page?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have jQuery UI tabs set up, but a problem that I'm having with links to different pages is that they load all contents of the page into the tab. This includes the footer, header, and other navbars that I don't want in the tab. What if I would only like to load a single ID from that page?

My tabs are set up this way:

```
<div id="mytabs">
<ul>
 <li><a href="derpsite.com/awesomepage">Awesome page</a></li>
 <li><a href="derpsite.com/foo">Foo</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Nothing much going on in the jQuery...

```
$(function() {
$( "#mytabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Let's say this is the html of "awesomepage" (that the first link targets):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>awesome page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">bla</div>
<div id="awesomeness">awesomeness!</div>
<div id="footer">fdsfd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

...And I only want the tab to load `#awesomeness` from the page. How would I go about doing this? I've read into some guides that do that by adding a `data-target="#youridhere"` attribute to the HTML, but I'm still confused on how to implement the javascript. It seems like this is a convenient solution, as I won't be targeting the same ID in every page. Any clues on how to get the javascript working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried putting data-target on the tab links specifying a valid CSS selector for the element on the target page? That's just a wild guess but if what you're referring to is accurate, that seems the most likely way to use that feature.

Comment: @DavidFells I tried it, but unfortunately `data-target="#blabla"` still ends up giving the entire page in the tab. I tried with a bunch of different CSS selectors just to make sure. Does external javascript have to be added to get this to work?

Comment: I don't know if the data-target should work, but I did not find anything on the official documentation. There is another solution, post process your content (remove unused content) with the callback : load: function( event, ui ) {}. It less efficient but it could be a temporary solution

Comment: You have another possibility, assuming you are generating your page with ASP, PHP or other Compiler: append a GET parameter to each URL of your tab and manage the parameter on the server side to check if you have to print the top/header/bottom section. you could have a parameter such as ?inside=true.

Comment: @user1073122 I'm using rails, and they do have a way to disable layout rendering. It's still a "meh" way around it though, because sometimes I want only a specific element. Even with the layout disabled, most of the page shows up, including parts I don't necessary need there. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution :) Using one of the answers as a reference point, the tabs can now load a single element specified in the `data-target` attribute. Here is the modified version:

```
$(function() {
$('#tabs').tabs(
{
beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {
if (ui.panel.children().size() > 0)
    return false;
ui.panel.load($('a', ui.tab).attr('href') + $('a', ui.tab).attr('data-target'));
return false;
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The function that allow to load partial code of the response is the $.load() function.
Unfortunately, the tabs() feature does not use this function but use $.ajax instead.

You can try this solution:

You can try to stop the default processing on the beforeLoad callback and manage your ajax call with the $.load() method.

(base on the 1.9 documentation, you may should adapt)

```
$('#tabs').tabs({

// Callback run when selecting a tab
beforeLoad: function(event, ui) {

    // If the panel is already populated do nothing
    if (ui.panel.children().size() > 0)
        return false;

    // Make your own ajax load (with fragment feature)
    ui.panel.load(ui.tab.attr('href') + ' #yourFragment');

    // stop the default process (default ajax call should not be launched)
    return false;
});
```

NOTICE: I'm not sure about extracting the URL with `ui.tab.attr('href')`, check before what object is ui.tab, but it should be easy to retrieve the href parameter.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working very well, except for the part you mentioned about URL extraction. The console gives me a 404. Everything works fine when I plop in a full url to replace `ui.tab.attr('href')`. After reading through the documentation, I actually still have no clue how to go about extracting the URL - any clues?